# How to get orders within dates range?

Tags: magento-1.9, orders

My script is working "fine" ... almost, quiet often skipping orders created around 00:00 -> 01:00
Asked server administrator, he confirmed the time (correct), checked timezone etc.
What can cause this issue ? there is no magic in it so i'm confused ...

```
$torders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToSort('increment_id', 'DESC')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from' => $from,'to' => $now))
        ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('nin' => array('canceled')));
```

time:

```
$fr = Mage::getModel('core/date')->date('Y-m-d');
$om = ' 00:00:00';
$from = $fr.$om;
$time = Mage::getModel('core/date')->timestamp(time());//-3600
$now = date('Y-m-d H:m:i', $time);
```

definitely everything is ... ok;

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, you're trying to get only the current day orders.
Try this:

```
$from = Mage::getModel('core/date')->date('Y-m-d');
$from = $from . ' 00:00:00';

$now = Mage::getModel('core/date')->date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from'=> $from, 'to'=> $now))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('neq' => Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CANCELED))
    ->addAttributeToSort('increment_id', 'DESC')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```